# Hiding and Displaying Images in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a very simple app. I have a timer, and when the timer exceeds 5 seconds, I want to have an image appear. If the timer not exceed 5 second, the image should remain hidden.  The problem is, I have my image appearing on my `main.storyboard`, I just can't seem to make it disappear once the timer exceeds 5 seconds. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int CountNumber;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *TimerDisplay;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Images;
    NSTimer *Timer;
}
-(void)TimerCount;
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Stop:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Restart:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *FirstiPhoneapp;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ByJ;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ClickToStart;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Reset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Terminate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Restart;
```

@end

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender
{
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target: self selector:@selector(TimerCount) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)TimerCount {
    CountNumber = CountNumber + 1;
    TimerDisplay.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountNumber];
}

- (IBAction)UIImage:(id)sender {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"Images.jpg"]];
    if (CountNumber < 6);
    Images.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)Stop:(id)sender{
    [Timer invalidate];
    TimerDisplay.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountNumber]; 
}

- (IBAction)Reset:(id)sender{
    CountNumber = 0;
    [Timer invalidate];
    CountNumber = 0;
    [Timer invalidate];
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountNumber];

    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(TimerCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];              
    [Timer invalidate];       
}

- (IBAction)Restart:(id)sender{
    CountNumber = 0;
    TimerDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", CountNumber];
    CountNumber = 0;
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(TimerCount) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

    if (CountNumber < 6);
    Images.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Also, for some reason, and any help on this would be helpful, I'm getting an error on `[super viewDidLoad];` Xcode is saying that it "expected method body." I've been looking around and can't find a solution to this, can anybody help me fix this error??

Comment: The images are appearing even though the code doesn't compile?  That's surprising.  As in c, objective-c code is delimited with {curly braces}.  That's what's wrong with viewDidLoad.

Comment: Your code is really low quality - you have semicolons that cause unwanted behavior. Also you shouldn't repeat the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change the following code in method "Restart" and "UIImage"

```
if (CountNumber < 6);
Images.hidden = YES;
```

to

```
if (CountNumber < 6){
   Images.hidden = YES;
}
```

And as I assume you're new to programming here a tip: The convention is that method-names are always written small, so in your code it should be "restart" / "start" instead of "Restart" / "Start".

And second, if I understand your code right, you made a mistake in your concept. The method that gets called by your timer is `TimerCount`. You have to put every UI-Functionality in there or call methods from there. This is the only method that is called every second. So you should put the

```
if (CountNumber < 6){
       Images.hidden = YES;
}
```

check in there.

Comment: Thank you!  And yes, I am new to programming, I'm 14 and I started learning last week.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You receive an error on `[super viewDidLoad];` because you forgot bracers.